# When i run docker official GPG key i got error

Tags: openai-gym

"curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -"
then i got error
"curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 172.31.1.3:8080"
"gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found." this

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
curl -O https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add gpg
```